# How to create a trivia crack-like spinner in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have tried to use Canvas, but it is terribly jerky and slow (like, a couple frames per second slow) on both iOS and android. From my other research, it looks  like using canvas does not work well on react native. I've tried a few different canvas samples to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I just need a spinner to spit out a random result, and I am having difficulty getting started.

Comment: Hi, I have not used it but I think this component may help you https://github.com/micahrye/react-native-animated-sprite. Best.

Comment: @milkersarac, thanks, checking it out now. Not sure how to get what value it would be pointing at, but I'll figure it out eventually.